# No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload | Django - Webhooks - Stripe

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I am using stripe and I am trying to connect webhooks to my local computer using django
here is the code I am using to receive Stripe webhooks requet that tell me whether the Payment was secced or not:

```
@csrf_exempt
def StripeWebhookView(request): 
    
    CHECKOUT_SESSION_COMPLETED = "checkout.session.completed"
    # Listen for success payment

    payload = request.body    
    sig_header = request.META["HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE"]
    endpoint_secret=settings.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET
    
    try:
        event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
            payload,
            sig_header,
            endpoint_secret
        )
        
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
        return HttpResponse(status=400)

    except SignatureVerificationError as e:
        print(e)
        return HttpResponse(status=400)

    if event["type"] == CHECKOUT_SESSION_COMPLETED:
        print(event)
```

what happens is :

1. charge succeeded
2. than Stripe try to send Request with the dat about the purchase but get error 400
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr5Q4.png)

so I check out and found that I need to : **"Make sure you're using the webhook signing secret which matches the Webhook Endpoint delivering the Event, which you can find in the Dashboard after selecting a specific Webhook Endpoint**" ([text](https://support.stripe.com/questions/webhooks-what-to-do-when-the-http-status-code-starts-with-a-four-(4xx)-or-five-(5xx)?locale=de-DE)

So i double chekc my "webhook signing secret key" **and even wrote it directly in my app**:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssm7t.png)
the problem is gone and the request from Stripe is received by my computer !

To make sure I didn;t make any mistake configuring env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET :

1. I double check and the secret key I set in .env (env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET) file is the same  webhook signing secret key   I was given in stripe
2. I have also printed  env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET  and got the excpected string equal to my "webhook signing secret key"

The problem is with env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRE
**The quetion is why???**

- Maybe it's take too much time for my computer to return http response because checking out the env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET ??

I know that my local server is very slow and it takes him a lot of time to return http response ...

Any idea ?

Comment: If you're testing this locally on your computer, you need to make sure that your code is using the Webhook signing secret that the stripe listen CLI command outputted (not the webhook signing secret from the dashboard).

Comment: I can use the CLI to produce a secret key, but I should be able to use the  "webhook signing secret key" form my dashboard. I have prof that because I have already succeed to recieve a webhook when I directly wrote it: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssm7t.png)

Comment: There is a problem with retrieveing the "webhook signing secret key" form .env file

Comment: So i found the reason for my bug: apperently I must create https doamin which receive Stripe Webhooks events ( and I didn't ) . This is why any time Stripe tried to send me Webhooks event it returned 404 because Stripe comunicate only with https request/response. So I used ngrok to create https domain and everything worked just fine. thanks @codename_duchess